# How do you avoid concordion:run running tests twice

Tags: java, concordion

Using concordion, it is possible to create "index" fixtures that use the concordion:run command to run a test.  E.g.

```
<a concordion:run="concordion" href="myLengthytest.html">The lengthy test</a>
```

My tests are all set up to use SpringJunitRunner as [per the tip here](https://code.google.com/p/concordion/issues/detail?id=6).

I tried excluding the fixtures from the failsafe plugin, but including the runner that calls them i.e.

```
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*FixtureIndex.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Fixture.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
```

Where in this case the "Fixture" files are the fixtures and the "FixtureIndex" is the index file with the concordion:run statements.  This seemed like a reasonable approach, but still seems to run the tests twice.. bizarrely.

I found this question [elsewhere](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/concordion/conversations/topics/489), but no useful answers were given, so having struck the the exact same problem, just thought I'd ask here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work OK, unless the SpringJUnitRunner is introducing some issue.

You might want to try just using:

```
 <includes>
     <include>**/*FixtureIndex.java</include>
 </includes>
```

An example of this working is the [concordion-extensions-demo](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-extensions-demo) project (without Spring).

Comment: Thanks Nigel - my problem was that I was using an older version of concordion - I upgraded to 1.4.3 and it seems to work now.  In the meantime I am doing the tests slightly differently so don't need the concordion:run (just tried it out so I could tick your answer :)).